# Problema realizando un bucle en python para pasar variables de un json de varios registros a html

Tags: html, python, json, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de pasar datos recibidos en formato de `JSON` a una plantilla `HTML`, esta es la forma en la que envío los datos a la plantilla:

Lo primero de todo es leer el `JSON` y guardar los datos deseados de este en un diccionario, se van a dar dos casos: que en el `JSON` venga un único registro, caso en el que no tengo problemas y que en el `JSON` vengan más de un registro. El `JSON` que me llega tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
carrito = [ 
    {
        "nombre": "Rollitos de primavera",
        "precio": "2"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Rollitos vietnamita",
        "precio": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "nombre": "Arroz 3 delicias",
        "precio": "4"
    }
]
```

Como se puede ver en este caso consta de 3 registros.

Para empezar, desde el `script` en el que trabajo llamo a la `función modificar` y le paso los parámetros necesarios para que encuentre la plantilla `HTML` que quiero modificar.

```
# Función modificar
def modificar(path, plantilla):
    env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader(path))
    template = env.get_template(plantilla)
    return(template)
```

A continuación, tras la lectura de los datos recibidos en formato `JSON` almaceno estos en un único diccionario para insertarlos en el `HTML`.

```
# Crear el diccionario para pasar
dictorden = {
    "nombrePlato": lista_orden[i][0],        
    "precio": lista_precio[i][0]
}
```

Una vez tengo el diccionario, cargo este en la `función modificarTodo` y de esta forma cambio en el `HTML` los parámetros deseados:

```
# Función modificarTodo
def modificarTodo(template, dictorden):
    html2 = template.render(dictorden)
    f = open('html_modif.html', 'w')
    f.write(html2)
    f.close
```

Esta sería la plantilla html y así están nombrados los campos que van a ser sustituidos por los datos que hay en el diccionario:

```
<tr>
  <p style="font-size: 16px;">Detalles del pedido:</p>
  <p style="font-size: 14px;">{{nombrePlato}}{{precio}}€</p>
</tr>
```

Cuando solo tengo un único registro la plantilla html se modifica de forma correcta el problema llega cuando son mas registros. Para ello he intentado hacer uso de un bucle for de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in range(len(carrito)):
      dictorden = {
            "nombrePlato": lista_orden[i][0],        
            "precio": lista_precio[i][0]
      }
       modificarTodo(template, todo)
```

Y el problema que tengo es que solo modifica el `HTML` con el ultimo valor de la `i`, los anteriores es como que los sobre escribe y no los rellena.

Comment: Buen día, has hecho una buena primera pregunta con código y el problema específico, aún así te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio y obtener tu primer medalla.

Comment: No sé si fue un error al escribir la pregunta o si falten secciones de código pero ¿No deberías utilizar tu variable `dictorden` en lugar de `todo`?

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema se basa en 2 errores:

1. la opción `'w'` del open, sobreescribe sobre el archivo, y al estar abriendolo cada vez que recorres un elemento, estás guardando el primero, luego borrando el primero y escribiendo el segundo y así.
2. Por otro lado estás cerrando incorrectamente el archivo. deberías hacer `.close()` con los paréntesis.
   Dado tu diseño actual, lo correcto de todas formas sería usar el context manager y cambiar el modo de apertura del archivo para agregar cosas:

```
def modificarTodo(template, dictorden):
    html2 = template.render(dictorden)
    with open('html_modif.html', 'a') as f:
        f.write(html2)
```

El context manager abre el archivo y lo cierra cuando se sale de ese contexto, con lo cual no hace falta el `close`. Por otro lado la opción `'a'` permite agregar  contenido al mismo archivo.
Te aconsejo que en el template render le agregues un salto de línea al final '\n' de cada entrada para que sea legible después.

---

Por otra parte creo que abrir el archivo y volver a cerrarlo en cada iteración no es la solución más prolija, puesto que puede ser más costoso que abrir el archivo una vez e iterar sobre cada elemento dentro de ese contexto para agregar todo en una sola apertura.